# css placeholder selector only not work for color

Tags: css, webpack, placeholder, css-loader, postcss-loader

I have tried ::placeholder or ::-webkit-input-placeholder selector for input to change placeholder's color.But I find only setting color was failed, other attributes like text-align or font-weight work well.
Adding '!important' also not work.I have used vue-loader && css-loader && autoprefixer.But it works well in codepen with only simple input and simple css code.
Here is my webpack config

```
[
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap=true']
        },{
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'less-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        loaders: {
                            scss: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                            css: 'style-loader!css-loader'
                        },
                        postcss: [
                            require('autoprefixer')({
                                browsers: ['Android >= 4', 'ChromeAndroid >= 46', 'iOS >= 8']
                            })
                        ],
                        esModule: false
                    }
                }]
        }]
```

Comment: please share your simple code.

Comment: Please share your code with jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 71). https://jsbin.com/kalebogine/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Amadan It's all depend of browser... for example in FF 47.0.2 not working.

Comment: It [seems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder#Browser_compatibility) FF is fine from v51, before that it needs `-moz-`.. (@nelek: yeah, I specifically named my browser for that purpose, I was trying to nudge OP to give more info). I don't have a FF that oild; works in FF 63.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code that may set alignment and color for the placeholder.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Edge */
  color: red;
  text-align:center;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer */
  color: red;
  text-align:center;
}

::placeholder {
  color: red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried like this way.But only text-align works, color doesn't change

Comment: I have checked it with w3school demo and add this is working

Comment: Can you please check that any other CSS is not there for same

Answer (score 0):

I finally find `-webkit-text-fill-color` which cover color, no matter if use `!important` ...